# Audio Sampling on Debian

Tags: c++, audio, debian, alsa

We're running Debian with ALSA, and we need to extract audio samples from our audio input line. We want to be able to fill a buffer with these samples, so perform operations on them as they come.

We have tried directly looking into ALSA calls yet we are running into issues with depreciated  functions since a lot of the resources out there are quite old.

Any good references or advice in terms of direction regarding this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some up-to-date example, like this:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

static char *device = "default"; /* capture device */

unsigned short buffer[2 * 24000];

int main(void)
{
    int err;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_sframes_t frames;

    if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((err = snd_pcm_set_params(handle,
                                  SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16,
                                  SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED,
                                  2,
                                  48000,
                                  1,
                                  500000)) < 0) { /* 0.5 sec */
        printf(" open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (;;) {
        frames = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, 24000);
        if (frames < 0)
            frames = snd_pcm_recover(handle, frames, 0);
        if (frames < 0) {
            printf("snd_pcm_readi failed: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
            break;
        }

        // ...
    }

    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://jackaudio.org/

acording to wikipedia:

> JACK Audio Connection Kit (or JACK) is a professional sound server daemon that provides real-time, low latency connections for both audio
>   and MIDI data between applications that implement its API. JACK is a
>   recursive acronym. JACK has been developed by a community of open
>   source developers led by Paul Davis (who won an Open Source Award in
>   2004 for this work)[3] and has been a key piece of infrastructure and
>   the de facto standard for professional audio software on Linux since
>   its inception in 2002. The server is free software, licensed under the
>   GNU GPL, while the library is licensed under the more permissive GNU
>   LGPL.